# Android setting background to fit screen size using cocos2d

Tags: android, glsurfaceview, cocos2d-android

I am using cocos2d to develop my android game.I am using following code to set background of screen.

```
        CGSize winSize = CCDirector.sharedDirector().displaySize();
    CCSprite player = CCSprite.sprite("map_image.png");
    player.setScaleX(winSize.getWidth()/player.getTexture().getWidth());
    player.setScaleY(winSize.getHeight()/player.getTexture().getHeight());
    player.setPosition(CGPoint.make(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2));
    addChild(player);
```

I am scaling background so as to fit screen size.but it is stretching background.Please suggest any other alternative.How i should take images to fit different sizes of backgrounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different images for different resolution, that give you best graphics result. You can check the screen size and according to that define the image for sprite for that resolution.

```
CCSprite player;
    if(size=...)
{
player = CCSprite.sprite("map_image_ldpi.png");
}else if(size=...)
{
player = CCSprite.sprite("map_image_mdpi.png");
}
.
.
.
```

[Images handling in cocos2d android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024927/images-handling-in-cocos2d-android/15085820#15085820)

Comment: thanks.i need some tutorial to use cocos2d for android can you please suggest something.

Comment: I am also developing cocos2d game. I have also searched on google for tutorial but there is nothing important doc. Its better to see the cocos2d org.cocos2d.tests package in cocos2d project. That help you.

Comment: long ago...but i need help
so m asking.....is it good practise to take images in drawables instead of in assets?

Comment: Yes. Because android will provide way to directly access file using id's , but in case of assets you have to use assets manager and other things to access.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is use pics that are bigger than any screen size (no streching used) and on some screens the edges are just not visible

Comment: thanks i am using same thing now.any other process do you know by which i can't loose quality of image.