# Android cocos2d fit sprite to screen

Tags: java, android, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I make a game with cocos2d ported on android and i'm try to stretch CCSprite to fit screen. I founded the answer [Images handling in cocos2d android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024927/images-handling-in-cocos2d-android/15085820#15085820) but this way suggests a big blow on size the app. Do you have another suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the scale of the sprite? You could calculate the factor between sprite and screen dimensions, and apply it to the sprite scale.

Comment: Yes, i tried. And i have strange result : Image scale on width normally, but when image scale on height, image stretch on bottom. I try to put result like image here later.

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't have some reputation points to post image here.